Legality of Purchasing Uncensored International Versions of Adult Games While Residing in Japan
I have recently moved to Japan and understand that adult games and other adult content must be censored by law when sold in Japan. I am interested in purchasing international versions of such content without censorship, for example from JAST USA. My question is: am I legally allowed to purchase and possess these uncensored international versions while residing in Japan as it would count as import? If there are any specific laws or regulations regarding this, I would appreciate detailed information on them.
Thank you for your assistance.

Probably a better fit on https://anime.stackexchange.com

@BlueDogRanch, ok, thank you

according to Wikipedia: "A person who distributes, sells or displays in public an obscene document, drawing or other objects shall be punished by imprisonment with work for not more than 2 years, a fine of not more than ¥2,500,000 or a petty fine. The same shall apply to a person who possesses the same for the purpose of sale."  Not sure about import laws or even how that might apply to an on-line purchase.

Cross-posted to Anime.SE but closed: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/68973/2516. Related/possibly dupe: Is uncensorship in Japanese porn illegal?.
